как скачать flutter приложение на ios
хочу скачать свое flutter приложение, но нет эпл девелопмент подписки. В хCode нашел только возможность запуска приложения на ревльном устройстве, но его невозможно запустить без подключения к мак. Есть ли способ установки приложения без траты 100$?

Если приложение собирается локально на маке, его можно бесплатно установить на своё устройство (сборка будет работать ограниченное количество времени), для этого действительно требуется подключить его к компьютеру, но Apple Developer подписка для этого не нужна.
Если же нет возможности подключить телефон к устройству, его можно загрузить в TestFlight и установить на свой телефон оттуда. Однако для этого уже требуется подписка Apple Developer.
Самый радикальный и неофициальный способ – при установке jailbreak на девайс установку приложения можно значительно упростить и устанавливать их напрямую из сгенерированных Xcode архивов.
